# Intuition for Calderon-Zygmund operator?

Tags: intuition, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

What is the best intuition for Calderon-Zygmund operators? Why are they so important in singular integrals, and complementary, which singular integrals don't they cover?

Comment: Whether there is such a thing as a "best" intuition for anything is debatable. People's brains are different, so what works well as intuition for one person may not work well for another.

Comment: Have you read Stein's book? Differentiability properties and so on?

Answer (score 3):

The best intuition is the Hilbert transform which is defined for suitable class of functions $f$ as $\mathcal H f (x):= \lim _{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x-t|\geq \epsilon} \frac{f(t)}{x-t}~dt$. According to Marcel Riesz's famous [convexity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem), $\mathcal H$ is a bounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$. The proof itself is of great importance, because it used complex method to prove a real theorem. The Hilbert transform is an important operator, for example if $\phi = u+iv$ is an analytic function, $\mathcal H$ relates the value of $u$ and $v$ on the line $y=0$. For more about the Hilbert transform see first chapter of M. Christ's book. S. Krantz says that (chapter 2 of the book cited):

> The Hilbert transform is, without question, the most important
>   operator in analysis.

With this brief introduction to the Hilbert transform, it is basic example of a (Calderon-Zygmund) singular integral operators, and the only one in the case $n=1$. Calderon and Zygmund generalized M. Riesz' idea to higher dimensions, and thus the theory of singular integral created. The immediate generalizations of Hilbert transform on higher dimensions called Riesz transforms: for $i=1,2,\dots n$ the operator $\mathcal R^i$ is defined as: 
$\mathcal R^i f (x):= \lim _{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x-t|\geq \epsilon} \frac{x_i -t_i}{|x-t|^{n+1}}f(t)~dt$. Riesz transforms $\mathcal R^i$ are also bounded on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

You could find some historical background in a paper that E. Stein published in the Notices of AMS. There are also many applications of theory, for example in partial differential equations, geometric measure theory, and so on.

*Stein, Elias M.*, Singular integrals: The roles of Calderón and Zygmund, Notices Am. Math. Soc. 45, No.9, 1130-1140 (1998). [ZBL0973.01027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0973.01027).

*Calderón, Alberto P.; Zygmund, Antoni*, [**On the existence of certain singular integrals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392130), Acta Math. 88, 85-139 (1952). [ZBL0047.10201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0047.10201).

*Krantz, Steven G.*, [**Explorations in harmonic analysis. With applications to complex function theory and the Heisenberg group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4669-1), Applied and Numerical Harmonic Analysis. Basel: Birkhäuser (ISBN 978-0-8176-4668-4/hbk; 978-0-8176-4669-1/ebook). xiv, 360 p. (2009). [ZBL1171.43001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1171.43001).

*Christ, Michael*, Lectures on singular integral operators. Expository lectures from the CBMS regional conference held at the University of Montana, Missoula, MT (USA) from August 28-September 1, 1989, Regional Conference Series in Mathematics. 77. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). ix, 132 p. (1990). [ZBL0745.42008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0745.42008)..